# Troubles with Mastermind game

Tags: ruby, oop

I'm trying to become better at OOP and wanted to create a Mastermind game.
The program consists of three classes, a Computer class where a random code of colors is created. A player class where the player input is stored, and a Game class that runs the game.
The problem I'm having is when I need to compare the random code from the Computer class with the player input.
Here's the code:

```
class Game

    def initialize
        @theComputer = Computer.new
        @player = Player.new
    end 

    def play

        print "\n\nThe Random code is:\n#{@theComputer.random_code}\n\n"

        10.times do |i|

            current_guess = @player.guess_code
            standing = evaluate_guess(current_guess)

        end 

    end #end play

    def evaluate_guess(current_guess) 

        current_guess.each_with_index do |color, position|

            print "#{match?(color, position)} "

        end 
        puts ""
    end

    def almost_match?(color) 
        @theComputer.random_code.include?(color)
    end

    def match?(color, position) 
        color == @theComputer.random_code[position]

    end
end

class Computer

    COLORS = ["B", "G", "R", "O", "Y", "P"]

    attr_reader :random_code

    def initialize
        @random_code = secret_code
    end
    def secret_code 
        sample_code = []
        sample_code << COLORS.sample(4)
        sample_code
    end
end 

class Player

    def guess_code
        puts "Guess the code! Choose 4 colors from B, G, R, O, Y, P"
        guess = gets.chomp
        guess.split(" ")
    end
end 

g = Game.new
g.play
```

I printed out the Random code and entered the matching values, but everything is returned as "false". And I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your secret_code method to this:

```
def secret_code
  COLORS.sample(4)
end
```

In your case the output of the secret code was

```
[[ random values from COLORS constant ]]
```

but you expected just simple array for the matching.

Comment: Thanks man! beens struggling with this problem for hours. Can't believe it was this simple..